# I am trying to connect to sftp server

Tags: php, ssh, sftp, phpseclib

I am using phpseclib to connect to sftp server.

here is my code

```
$this->sftp = new Net_SFTP($host, $port);
        $login = $this->sftp->login($user, $password);

        if (!$login) {
            throw new SGExceptionForbidden('Could not connect to the SFTP server: '.$host);
        }
```

but it says No compatible server to client encryption algorithms found

what can I do to solve this issue

Comment: Why you don't use ssh2_connect? http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-connect.php

Comment: To use ssh2_connect you have to install libssh2-php library. `sudo apt-get install libssh2-php & sudo service apache2/nginx restart`

Comment: If you have to use phpselib then please make sure that you had included the library path and file correctly. `set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');` `include('phpseclib/Net/SFTP.php');`

Comment: @user3918128 - so are you now able to connect?

Comment: Yes I am. @neubert